# How to use Leaflet.js in a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I am going through the [Leaflet Tips and Tricks](https://leanpub.com/leaflet-tips-and-tricks/read#leanpub-auto-making-maps-with-d3js-and-leafletjs-combined) book and I can get the below example from the book working easily on [bl.ocks.org](https://bl.ocks.org/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Leaflet Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link 
        rel="stylesheet" 
        href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css"
    />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

    <script
        src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js">
    </script>

    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505431, -0.023533], 14);
        mapLink = 
            '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
        L.tileLayer(
            'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
            maxZoom: 18,
            }).addTo(map);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I need some guidance on converting this to work in a Visualforce page.

The below is not working for me:

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css" />
    <apex:includescript value="//http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js" />

    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
    <head>
    <script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([-41.2858, 174.78682], 14);
    mapLink = 
        '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
    L.tileLayer(
        'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
            maxZoom: 18,
        }).addTo(map);
    </script>
    </head>
</apex:page>
```

Can someone advise how I can use leaflet.js in a Visualforce page like this?

EDIT:

As per tip by Rahul Sharma, in the Chrome console log, I can see four errors:

[image]

Comment: Do you see any JavaScript errors in developer tools/console

Comment: Thanks - I added the errors. I am unsure why I am getting those errors if it works as a .html file (the first version).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first, you'll want to use a HTTPS CDN versus a normal HTTP. Just replacing the two URLs with some cloudflare ones I found with some google fu get the example working.

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:stylesheet value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.3/leaflet.css" />
    <apex:includescript value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.3/leaflet.js" />

    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
    <head>
        <script>
            var map = L.map('map').setView([-41.2858, 174.78682], 14);
            mapLink = '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors', maxZoom: 18,}).addTo(map);
        </script>
    </head>
</apex:page>
```

However, I highly recommend taking the resources from the CDN and turning them into a Static Resource, which is the recommended way to use a third-party javascript library with Salesforce.

Recommended Reading:

[Creating a Static Resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources_create.htm)

[Referencing a Static Resource in Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources_reference.htm)